# Sharemouse: Disable wifi / disable automatic client configuration

Tags: networking, synergy, crossover-cable, crossover

G'day, 
Is it possible to disable the use of wifi networks/automatic client configs in sharemouse v4.0.46?

Sharemouse will automatically configure to wifi (which is laggy) rather then ethernet (direct cable from my PC to macbook pro) which works great. Every time i restart either computer it automatically chooses the wifi network as preferred address.

Is there a way to block certain IP addresses (192.168.xxx.xx) from automatic configuration? I've looked in the preferenced and played around in the client configuration page but have not found a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You select the preferred network adapter by entering its IP address in the settings (Settings -> Clients). Make sure to untick "Automatic find clients".